# Adding a variable to CREATE TABLE name using pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, database, create-table, pymysql

I need to change the way my Python script is creating my table names. I currently have:

```
import pymysql
import datetime
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


now = datetime.datetime.now()
today = now.strftime("%m%d%y")

conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', passwd='xxxxx',             db='database', charset='utf8')

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE `"+today+"` ( Revenue varchar(255), Free varchar(255), Paid varchar(255), Game varchar(255), Price varchar(255), Revenue2 varchar(255), ARPU_Index varchar(255), Daily_New_Users varchar(255), Daily_Active_Users varchar(255), ARPU varchar(255), Rank_Change varchar(255))")
```

I need to change

```
today = now.strftime("%m%d%y")
```

so that

```
"CREATE TABLE `"+today+"`
```

Returns me something like this:

day+i

where i is a variable integer that increases each time a table is created.

I run this script daily, so there's a new table for every day. Right now it names them like this:

```
041014
041114
041214
etc...
```

Does anyone know how I can do this or have any resources for table creating using Python?

Comment: @halfer thanks for editing. I'm totally lost on how to iterate a variable, if you have any thoughts please let me know.

Comment: Not a Python person, unfortunately. I would say that table names containing just numbers should probably be avoided if you can help it, or at least give them a suitable prefix. Better still, have one table and a date column.

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL, you can query how many Tables there are that start with `day`. Make sure that only the Tables you are interested in start with `day`.

```
SELECT COUNT(TABLE_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='database' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'day%'
```

Next, use this number, add 1 to it, and create in Python the correct string for the table name.

```
today = 'day {0}'.format(nr_tables_with_day+1)
```